# Suggested edits approved by

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I just had a suggested edit approved (yay for the new system), but I was expecting to see an "Approved by [Mr X], [Mr Y]" type message when I clicked on the details of the Edit (The Revisions page). Much like when seeing the list of users who closed a question, etc.

I could also understand that it doesn't really matter...just that I was expecting to see it.

Comment: confirmed, we need to have an audit trail in history.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: audit trail]

There is a clickable audit trail in revisions. With rich information about the edit.

Comment: Chuk? How do I chuk that?

Comment: LOL using your chuck finger :)